# Missing return statement in a method

Tags: java, methods

I encountered a problem with the method which identifies missing return statement. Whats the problem here?

```
public static int doThisEven(int n) {
    if (n == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return n + doThisEven(n - 1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your method returns nothing when `n` is odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a code that garanties a return to the method no mather what with the if else conditions happen

```
if (n == 2) {
        return 2; // return if n is 2
    } else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return n + doThisEven(n - 1); return 2; // return if n is off
        }
    }
```

your code is returning when

1. n=2
2. n is even

but what if n+none of the above, lets say n=3??
then the method will never find a return statement so you are voilating the contract of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return a value in all cases:

```
public static int doThisEven(int n) {
    if (n == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return n + doThisEven(n - 1);
        }

    }
    return 0;//if none of the previous cases are true
}
```

You can also try this:

```
public static int doThisEven(int n) {
if (n == 2) {
    return 2;
} else {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n + doThisEven(n - 1);
    }else
    {
        return 0;//if none of the previous cases are true
    }

}
```

Note that return 0; is not the number that you should return, i just made an example of the return statement that you should make in order for the program to compile.

Comment: but that would make the else part unnecessary. It should be return n?

Comment: I would raise an exception instead of returning a default value. Because if the logic will change in the future and the method could return 0 on some value, then this could cause a problem.

Comment: @J.Koh - a function must return a value to **all** the cases!

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative solution to your problem.